# Creating different csv files from a list whose elements are dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, csv

I have a list of dataframes and I need to convert each dataframe into a separate csv file with a unique name. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html` ?

Comment: This will work for one file but I am unable to loop it over every element of the list and a unique name to be generated for each file

Comment: `[df.to_csv(f'file_name{i}.csv') for i, df in enumerate(list_of_df)]`?

Comment: @Axe319 Hey, thank you so much! It worked perfectly.